# How to join these tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have one table "**Rule**" with several IDs which is from either of 3 tables **A,B,C**.

Structure is like this:

---

Table = Rule

Column = ID

```
ID 
--

222

333

555

7899
```

---

Table = A

Column = ID, Email

```
ID        Email

111       test111@gmail.com
555       test555@gmail.com
```

---

Table = B

Column = ID, Email

```
ID        Email

222       test222@gmail.com
7899      test7899@gmail.com
```

---

Table = C

Column = ID, Email

```
ID        Email

333       test333@gmail.com
444       test444@gmail.com
```

---

I need the result like :

```
ID    Email

222   test222@gmail.com

333   test333@gmail.com

555   test555@gmail.com
7899  test7899@gmail.com
```

NOTE : A, B, C tables also contains some more info, they are not exactly identical.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear..Please see my edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  d.*
FROM    rule
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  id, email
        FROM    a
        WHERE   a.id = rule.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, email
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.id = rule.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, email
        FROM    c
        WHERE   c.id = rule.id
        ) d
```

Note that if `id` is present in more than one table, records from all tables with that `id` will be returned.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is not necessary and is no more efficient in this case

Comment: @YouAreWhatYouIs: are you proposing a change to the answer?

Comment: @Quassnoi No - your answer works but I am just pointing out that CROSS APPLY is not necessary i.e. there are other solutions that don't use it.

Comment: @YouAreWhatYouIs: ok, no problem. I thought you maybe wanted to back your statement about "no more efficient".

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    r.id,
    e.email
from rule r
left outer join (
    select id, email from A
    union all 
    select id, email from B
    union all
    select id, email from C
    ) as e on r.id = e.id
```

This will return all records from the "rule" table even if there are no matching records in tables A, B or C